# Calculating MSE of MOM and MLE of a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be a random sample of size three from a $uniform(θ, 2θ)$ distribution, where $θ > 0$

I solved to get $\tilde{\theta}_{MoM}$ to be $\frac{2\bar{x}}{3}$.

Also, I got $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ to be $\frac{X_n}{2}$.

For the c part, I am trying to find the MSE for both MoM and MLE estimators. I used the formula $MSE(\theta) = Var(\theta) + (Bias(\theta))^2$

For the MoM estimator part, I am able to find the $MSE(\theta)$ to be $\frac{\theta^2}{27}$ but for the MLE part, I think I have to find the distribution of $X_n$ before I can be able to find variance and expected value.

Can someone help me with that, confirm if the MSE of the MoM estimator is also correct, and guide me on the MSE of the MLE estimator?

Comment: I do not think your mean-square error of $\theta^2/27$ is quite correct - I think it is too large, i.e. the $27$ is too small.  How did you calculate it?

Comment: The probability $X_{(n)} \le x$ is the probability all of $X_1,X_2,X_3 \le x$

Comment: Calculating the bias of $\tilde{\theta}$ is 0. And since it is unbiased, the MSE of $\tilde{\theta}$ is equal to the variance. Thus, $MSE =  \frac(4}{9}Var(\bar{X})$. $\bar{X} \sim U(\theta, 2\theta)$, thus $Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\theta^2}{12}$. Hence the $MSE = \frac{\theta^2}{27}$. That is how I got the MSE of $\tilde{\theta}$

Comment: I dont actually know if I am correct, thus seeking on guidance on how to solve the MSE for both estimators.

Comment: Not quite: each $Var(X_i)=\frac{\theta^2}{12}$ so  $Var(\bar X)=\frac19 3Var(X_i)= \frac{\theta^2}{36}$ so $Var(\frac23 \bar X)=\frac49 \frac{\theta^2}{36}= \frac{\theta^2}{81}$.

Comment: Got you. What about MLE?

Comment: As I said earlier, the probability $X_{(n)} \le x$ is the probability all of $X_1,X_2,X_3 \le x$.  This is $\left(\frac{(x-\theta)^3}{\theta^3}\right)$  so the density for  $X_{(n)}$ is $3\left(\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{\theta^3}\right)$  between $\theta$ and $2\theta$.  With that you can calculate $E\left[\left(\frac {X_{(n)}}{2}-\theta\right)^2\right]$

Comment: Are you sure you've computed your MLE correctly? Seems to me that $X_{(1)}$ should appear there somewhere.

Comment: I got the CDF as of @Henry. The pdf will be $3(\frac{y}{\theta}-1)^2.(\frac{1}{\theta}) = \frac{3}{\theta}(\frac{y}{\theta}-1)^2$. Hence it easy to find the bias and variance. The MSE can be computed.

Comment: @JoseAvilez  The likelihood is $\frac1{\theta^3} I_{[X_{(n)}\le 2\theta]}  I_{[X_{(1)}\ge \theta]}$.  Assuming $X_{(n)} \le 2 X_{(1)}$, this is maximised when $\theta$ is as small as possible, i.e. when $\theta=\frac {X_{(n)}}{2}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your method of moments estimator $\frac23 \bar X$:

each $\textrm{Var}(X_i)=\frac{\theta^2}{12}$ so $\textrm{Var}(\bar X)=\frac19 3Var(X_i)= \frac{\theta^2}{36}$ so $\textrm{Var}(\frac23 \bar X)=\frac49 \frac{\theta^2}{36}= \frac{\theta^2}{81}$

and since $\frac23 \bar X$ is unbiased, this means the expected mean square error is $\frac{\theta^2}{81}.$

---

For your maximum likelihood estimator $\frac {X_{(3)}}{2}$:

The probability $X_{(3)} \le x$ is the probability all of $X_1,X_2,X_3 \le x$.  This is $\frac{(x-\theta)^3}{\theta^3}$  so the density for  $X_{(3)}$ is $3\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{\theta^3}$  between $\theta$ and $2\theta$.

With that you can calculate the expected mean square error $E\left[\left(\frac {X_{(3)}}{2}-\theta\right)^2\right]=\int\limits_\theta^{2\theta}  3\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{\theta^3}\left(\frac x2-\theta\right)^2\,dx = \frac{\theta^2}{40}.$

If you wanted to split it into variance and square of bias, it would be $\frac{3 t^2}{320} + \frac{t^2}{64}= \frac{\theta^2}{40}$. By comparison, $\frac47 X_{(3)}$ would be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and have variance and expected mean square error $\frac{3 t^2}{245}$, slightly below that of your method of moments estimator, while $\frac{35}{62} X_{(3)}$ would have an even lower expected mean square error of $\frac{3 \theta^2}{248}$.

---

Whether some other combination of $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}$ could do better than this would be a longer exercise. It turns out that  with $\hat \theta = \frac5{12}X_{(3)} + \frac5{24}X_{(1)}$ $($very slightly biased as its expectation is $\frac{95}{96}\theta)$ you can reduce the expected mean square error to $\frac{\theta^2}{96}.$  But even this is not optimal, as when $X_{(3)} > \frac{19}{10}X_{(1)}$ it gives an implausible $\hat \theta > X_{(1)}$.  I came up with the complicated $ \frac{5 X_{(3)} X_{(1)} (2 X_{(1)}+X_{(3)}) (4 X_{(1)}^2+X_{(3)}^2)}{4 (16 X_{(1)}^4+8 X_{(3)} X_{(1)}^3+4 X_{(3)}^2 X_{(1)}^2+2 X_{(3)}^3 X_{(1)}+X_{(3)}^4)}$ which performed even better and a reasonably close approximation to this seems to be $\frac{1}{868} \left(736 X_{(3)} -80 X_{(1)} -131 \frac{X_{(3)}^2}{X_{(1)}}\right)$ both with an expected mean square error less than $\frac{\theta^2}{96.935}$.